# Running Ping -t from Java and ending process on closure

Tags: java, command, runtime

I have a simple GUI program where one of the features is to ping a destination from a file. I have the ping running fine when using normal ping x.x.x.x however when running this with the -t command i have noticed that even after closing the command window ping.exe is still showing in the process list. I know the process can be ended using ctrl+c but is there a different way to get the process to end when the user closes the cmd window?

i am currently using this code:

```
try {
            ipPing = VNC.getIp().concat(ext);
            String command = "ping " + ipPing;
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            rt.exec(command);
            rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "\"start;" + command + "\""});

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

any advice and tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure will it work, but you can try [Process.destroy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29). Something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "\"start;" + command + "\"");
Process p = pb.start();
//...
p.destroy();
```

Also, don't write empty catch blocks:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

because if an exception gets thrown it'll be hard to notice. Unless of course, you know that you can ignore the exception.

UPDATE:

proof of concept for linux os:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping","localhost");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    int ch,count = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while((ch =isr.read()) > -1) {            
        sb.append((char)ch);                
       if ((char)ch == '\n') {
          System.out.println( sb.toString());
          sb = new StringBuffer();
       }
       if (count++ == 2) {
           System.out.println("destroying process");
           p.destroy();
       }
    }        
}
```

outputs:

```
destroying process
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms

at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:308)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:107)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:93)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:151)
at com.infobip.rhino.Killer.main(Killer.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

the lines are messed up because the error stream is redirected to output stream

Comment: This will not work. It will be better if you will try it and become sure.